# Some help understanding and creating my own build system for ROS2

Tags: ros2

I would like to gain a greater understanding of how to build the ROS2 distribution. So far I've gotten to the point where I get that I understand that there is a suite of python scripts for generating jenkins jobs in order to build Ubuntu packages for e.g Humble Hawksbill.

I am in a situation where I might need to evaluate and use different distributions than Ubuntu, and occasionally I cannot use Docker or Podman, so I would like to learn how to build binary packages for other distributions.(There may also be situations where I need a different docker image than Ubuntu).

If anyone could please point me in the right direction in order for me to start figuring this out on my own and how the build system is set up, it would be greatly appreciated.